# 2nd order high pass filter bode plot

Tags: filter, bode-plot

I have this circuit and I am not sure how to create the bode plot and the actual bode plot.
[image: Circuit]

Comment: Please add some more details as to what specifically you are stuck on. Do you know how to draw bode plots in general? Do you know how to draw bode plots for first order circuits?

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in my opinion, you should view this circuit in the Laplace domain. So, in this case, the equivalent laplace capacitor is 1/(sC); after that it's just a matter of find the ratio between the output and the input (easily obtained with the simple partition rule, since in Laplace domain you can avoid differential equation stuff).
So the resulting polynomial ratio is your transfer function. Now that you have your transfer function you can plot the magnitude and phase by applying the classic rules (pole: -20dB/dec and -90°; zero: +20dB/dec and +90°. If you have second or higher order poles/zeros you have to double/triplicate/so on)